How to get the Revit Version of all ACC Projects
I'm accessing a list of projects in ACC and want to filter this list by the currently used Autodesk Revit Version within my app. I understand that only one version is allowed to be used at any one time in ACC.
Currently, I'm relying on users to know which version of Revit an ACC project is based. I would ideally like the list to be filtered based on the version they are currently using like the Revit ACC Home window currently allows.
Ideally, I don't want to have to iterate through all the project folders to find a RVT file to query directly for its version as this will significantly affect performance.
At this moment, I'm allow users to select any file they wish of any version and then query the file at this point for version alignment.

please reach out through aps[dot]help[at]autodesk[dot]com
